# How can I get the definition of a class in a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why can't I get the definition of `Callable` from module `collections` in the following code?

How can I get the definition of a class in a module? Thanks.

```
>>> from collections import Callable
>>> inspect.getsource(Callable)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 944, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 931, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 788, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not find class definition')
OSError: could not find class definition
>>> inspect.getsourcelines(Callable)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 931, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 788, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not find class definition')
OSError: could not find class definition
>>> inspect.getmodule(Callable)
<module 'collections.abc' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/collections/abc.py'>
>>> inspect.getfile(Callable)
'/usr/lib/python3.5/collections/abc.py'
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(Callable)
'/usr/lib/python3.5/collections/abc.py'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is easily done with [`inspect.getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) which accepts a module, a class, a method, a function, a traceback, a frame,
or a code object. The source they represent should of course be written in Python else an error is raised.

In this specific case, you just happen to be unlucky because while `Callable` is *defined* in `_collections_abc` [the `Callable.__module__` name is `callections.abc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L27):

```
>>> Callable.__module__
'collections.abc'
```

This throws `getsource` off because it won't look in `_collections_abc` that contains `Callable`s definition but, instead, in `collections.abc` which merely imports all definitions from `_collections_abc`:

```
>>> print(getsource(collections.abc))
from _collections_abc import *
from _collections_abc import __all__
```

Normally, `getsource` doesn't have an issue finding the source, for example, on itself:

```
>>> print(getsource(getsource))
def getsource(object):
    """Return the text of the source code for an object.

    The argument may be a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame,
    or code object.  The source code is returned as a single string.  An
    OSError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
    return ''.join(lines)
```

In this specific case, though, it does (due to `Callable.__module__` returning `collections.abc`.) You could replace `__module__` with `'_collections_abc'` for a tricky way to see the source:

```
>>> Callable.__module__ = '_collections_abc'
>>> src = getsource(Callable)  
>>> print(src)
class Callable(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    __slots__ = ()

    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return False

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Callable:
            return _check_methods(C, "__call__")
        return NotImplemented
```

but this doesn't make me feel very comfortable.

Comment: Thanks. Do `getsourceline` and `getsource` find the definition of an object `obj` via `obj.__module__`? So do they require `obj` be defined in Python, instead of binary code? Does `getfile` find the file of an object `obj` via `obj.__module__` too?

Comment: @Tim yes, `getsourceline` and `getsource` both internally use `getfile` which grabs the `__module__` from the `obj` if that is a class (which inspect determines by using `inspect.isclass`). Built-in modules (implemented in C in the case of CPython) can't be used with `inspect`, so yes, they *must* be defined in Python.

Answer (score 2):

**`get_source(fullname)`**
Return the source code for the specified module.

So you should return the whole module, as `Callable` is defined in the module of `_collections_abc`, so your code should be this:

```
import _collections_abc

import inspect

print(inspect.getsource(_collections_abc))
```

and you can see the definition of `Callable` in the print result.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean `inspect.getsource` can only apply to a module object? I saw it can apply to a function object to get the definition of a function. So why doesn't it apply to class `inspect.Callable`?

Comment: Maybe the function you mentioned are defined as one module? Not sure of that, but the definition of getsource I pasted is from the offical documents.